# KITL connection issue: WIN EC7

Tags: windows, windows-ce, platform-builder

I am using OpenBoard-AM335x from Phytec india and have installed WIN EC7.

My problem is, i can not create a KITL connection between platform builder and my device.

To create a KITL connection i have followed steps as below:

Device side setup:-

1. started device, opened EBOOT configuration at boot time
2. selected option '4' for Network settings in EBOOT main menu
3. set static-ip=192.168.0.182 subnet-mask=255.255.255.0 and router-ip=192.168.0.1(our router ip address, device is connected with LAN cable)
4. selected Boot from Internal EMAC from boot device menu

PC side setup:-

1. set ip of PC to 192.168.0.102, subnet-mask=255.255.255.0 and default gateway=192.168.0.1 (pc is connected with wi-fi router)
2. disabled firewall and anti-virus software
3. opened Target->Connectivity options in Visual studio 2008
4. Added device with target device name "AM335X" and Associated OS design with "Windows CE" in Add device menu
5. set Target device to "AM335X", Kernel Download to "Ethernet", Kernel Transport "Ethernet", Kernel Debugger to "KdStub" in Kernel Service Map menu
6. opened "settings" of Kernel Download
7. Now platform builder is waiting for active devices

Next, started device to boot with above described settings, the device starts to send messages "sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255" to serial console. But, nothing detected by platform builder.

Device's serial log is as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Main Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [1] Show Current Settings
 [2] Select Boot Device
 [3] Select KITL (Debug) Device
 [4] Network Settings
 [5] SDCard Settings
 [6] Set Device ID
 [7] Save Settings
 [8] Flash Management
 [9] Enable/Disable OAL Retail Messages
 [a] Select Display Resolution
 [b] Select OPP Mode
 [0] Exit and Continue

 Selection: 1

 Main:
  Boot device:   Internal EMAC
  Debug device:  Internal EMAC
  Retail Msgs:   disabled
  Device ID:     0
  Display Res:   7in LCD_017 (800x480@60Hz)
  Flashing NK.bin:   disabled
  OPP Mode:   MPU[720Mhz @ 1.26V]

 SDCard:
  Filename:      "nk.bin"

 Network:
  KITL state:    enabled
  KITL type:     active
  KITL mode:     interrupt
  DHCP:          disabled
  IP address:    192.168.0.182
  IP mask:       255.255.255.0
  IP router:     192.168.0.1
  Eth MAC Addr  :  00:18:31:8d:c6:92 (Boot settings)
  Eth MAC Addr 1:  00:18:31:8d:c6:93 (Boot settings)
  VMINI:         enabled
  Note: USBFN RNDIS MAC Addr cannot be changed.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Main Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [1] Show Current Settings
 [2] Select Boot Device
 [3] Select KITL (Debug) Device
 [4] Network Settings
 [5] SDCard Settings
 [6] Set Device ID
 [7] Save Settings
 [8] Flash Management
 [9] Enable/Disable OAL Retail Messages
 [a] Select Display Resolution
 [b] Select OPP Mode
 [0] Exit and Continue

 Selection: 0
ShowSDLogo
Init HW: controller RST
SDCARD: requested speed 1000000, actual speed 1000000
SDCARD: requested speed 25000000, actual speed 19200000
BLSDCardReadLogo:  cannot open Logo.bmp
+Cpsw3gInit(0x4a100000, 0x00000001, 0x8fefff6c) v0.3
Auto negotitation failed
Phy_init: Auto negotitation completed
Cpsw3gInit, wait link up on mac port:1.
Cpsw3gInit, LINK down on port:1.
INFO: Boot device uses MAC 00:18:31:8d:c6:92
INFO: *** Device Name AM335X-50834 ***
+EbootSendBootmeAndWaitForTftp
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
Sent BOOTME to 255.255.255.255
```

Any suggestions/comments ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)  or a similar tool to verify that the PC is receiving the BOOTME packets?

Comment: Yes. I have already installed Wireshark to catch BOOTME packets. but, it doesn't show anything. I have disabled firewall and anti-virus also.

Comment: You say that the PC is connected via a WiFi router. The WinCE device will be broadcasting the BOOTME packets - are you sure that the WiFi router is not blocking the broadcast packets? If your PC is a laptop, the easiest thing to do may be to directly connect the PC and the WinCE device with an ethernet crossover cable as a first step.

Comment: I had tried with cross-over cable also. but it didn't either. I had configured as follows: laptop IP-192.168.0.102, netmask-255.255.255.0, default gateway-192.168.0.182.   WINEC7 device IP-192.168.0.182, default mask-255.255.255.0, ip router-192.168.0.102. I had tested cross-cable and it working.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have any firewall installed on your machine preventing platform builder from receiving packets from your device. If both machines are on the same IP subnet you should be able to receive broadcast packets. Usually if you have the Windows firewall enabled you will get a message reporting that platform builder is opening a port on your PC and if you don't allow the operation it will not be able to connect.